# Does passport OAuth2Strategy in Nodejs make automatic POST request for access token

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, access-token, passport.js

passport.js

```
passport.use(new OAuth2Strategy({
   authorizationURL: ' https://gymkhana.iitb.ac.in/sso/oauth/authorize',
   tokenURL: 'https://gymkhana.iitb.ac.in/sso/oauth/token',
   clientID: process.env.IITB_SSO_CLIENT_ID,
   clientSecret: process.env.IITB_SSO_CLIENT_SECRET,
   callbackURL: "http://192.168.0.111:8080/auth/iitbsso/callback"
},
 function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  console.log(accessToken);
 }
```

app.js

```
app.get('/auth/iitbsso', passport.authenticate('oauth2', { scope:'basic'}));
app.get('/auth/iitbsso/callback', passport.authenticate('oauth2', { 
   successRedirect: '/',
   failureRedirect: '/login' 
}), (req, res) => {
   res.redirect(req.session.returnTo || '/');
});
```

This is how I tried to get an accessToken from the server
But my server gets stuck at http://192.168.0.111:8080/auth/iitbsso/callback?code=TDPHtfHuKv4HWNhJikkFzNz5bR4fvJ

And I get undefined in the log.

So my question is:
1) Does this strategy make this POST request automatically or do I have to make it explicitly in the callback?

POST /sso/oauth/token/ HTTP/1.1

Host: gymkhana.iitb.ac.in

Authorization: Basic AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&grant_type=authorization_code

2) If it does then how do I make it work in my server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how does `Verify Callback` work.

have a look at http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/

more specifically, in your code

```
function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      console.log(accessToken);
      // call done(args) here!
}
```

to answer your question

`passport-oauth2` will handle all dirty work for you, access `/auth/iitbsso`, then redirect user, as specified in `/auth/iitbsso/callback`